# Make deactivated listings visible in Osclass

Tags: php, osclass

I have installed Osclass and I'm trying simply to **show deactivated listings to public**.

The system behaves in such a way that it displays the activated advertisements correctly both to the admin and to the users - this is CORRECT. But in the case of a disabled ad URL, an ad is displayed to the admin with a warning that the ad is not active, and users (not logged in as admin) get a 404 error. I need users to see **the same thing as admins** (listing with a warning, that the ad is not active).

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.